# Arrays constants can only be used in initializers error

Tags: java, arrays, multidimensional-array

Consider:

```
public proj 3 {

    static string [][]Item;

    public static void main(String [] args){

        Item[][] = {
             {"BH," , "Backhoe,"            , "200.00"},
             {"ER," , "Electric Rake,"      ,  "10.00"},
             {"EL," , "Electric Lawnmower," ,  "15.00"},
             {"TR," , "Trencher"            ,  "35.00"},
             {"MU," , "Mulcher,"            ,  "20.00"},
             {"TS," , "Tree Sprayer,"       ,  "22.00"},
             {"CP," , "Cider Press,"        ,  "30.00"},
             {"PR," , "Pruner,"             ,  "12.00"},
             {"GE," , "Gas Edger,"          ,  "20.00"},
             {"RO," , "Roller,"             ,   "8.00"},
```

How can I make it so I can call the array from a different method?

Comment: I really do not understand your question. Can you be a bit more specific. And please fix your code.

Comment: That doesn't really look much like Java.  What is `public proj 3{`?  `string` should probably be `String`.

Comment: Sorry about the sloppy code, the problem is i want to declare the multidementional array to make it a global variable. so the array can be called all throught the class.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

That means you have to initialize it like this:

```
public class Proj3{

    public static String [][] Item = {
              {"BH," , "Backhoe," , "200.00"},
              {"ER," , "Electric Rake," , "10.00"},
              {"EL," , "Electric Lawnmower," , "15.00"},
              {"TR," , "Trencher" , "35.00"},
              {"MU," , "Mulcher," , "20.00"},
              {"TS," , "Tree Sprayer," , "22.00"},
              {"CP," , "Cider Press," , "30.00"},
              {"PR," , "Pruner," , "12.00"},
              {"GE," , "Gas Edger," , "20.00"},
              {"RO," , "Roller," , "8.00"}
         };

public static void main(String [] args){
     ...
}
```

If you want to use the array initializer, you cannot split the declaration and assignment.

Comment: "If you want to use the array initializer, you cannot split the declaration and assignment." This. Thanks a bunch.

Comment: Except as described in various answers below, using the new operator, which is technically an exception to that rule.

Answer (score 8):

You have two options:
In the declaration

`private static String[][] item = {...};`

OR

Elsewhere using the `new` keyword
`private static String[][] item = new String[][]{...}`

Also, you'll need to change `public proj` to `public class`

Answer (score 0):

I'm not 100% sure if I got correctly what you mean, but you can reference static class members by fully qualifying it.

```
public class MyClass {
  // static class member
  public static String myStaticArray;

  // non-static class method
  public void myMethod() {
    MyClass.myStaticArray = {...}; // do stuff
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If your target is: 1. declare it somewhere; 2. initialize it somewhere else; 3. still want to use the {...} format.
This will work:

```
public proj 3 {

    static string [][]Item;

    public static void main(String [] args) {

        string[][] _Item = {
             {"BH," , "Backhoe," , "200.00"},
             {"ER," , "Electric Rake," , "10.00"},
             {"EL," , "Electric Lawnmower," , "15.00"},
             {"TR," , "Trencher" , "35.00"},
             {"MU," , "Mulcher," , "20.00"},
             {"TS," , "Tree Sprayer," , "22.00"},
             {"CP," , "Cider Press," , "30.00"},
             {"PR," , "Pruner," , "12.00"},
             {"GE," , "Gas Edger," , "20.00"},
             {"RO," , "Roller," , "8.00"}
        };
        Item = _Item;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can declare a multidimensional array globally like this:

```
String [][] 2DArray;
```

And then initialize the same in the main method as follows:

```
 2DArray = new String[][] {
                {"array_element_0", "array_element_1"},
                {"array_element_2", "array_element_3"},
                ...
            };
```