# Initializing array with values - should I explicitly instance the class or not?

Tags: java

I often see arrays being initialized like this:

```
String[] array = new String[] { "foo", "bar", "baz" };
```

But reading the [Language Basics - Arrays](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/arrays.html) shows that the short syntax doesn't require explicitly instancing the constructor:

> Alternatively, you can use the shortcut syntax to create and
>   initialize an array:
>
> ```
>  int[] anArray = { 
>      100, 200, 300,
>      400, 500, 600, 
>      700, 800, 900, 1000
>  };
> ```

---

So, assuming these two methods of initialization:

```
String[] array = new String[] { "foo", "bar", "baz" };
String[] array2 = { "foo", "bar", "baz" };
```

Is there any difference between these? Both seems to work the same, in that case should I assume that the second one implicitly calls the `new String[]` and the first one is just a more verbose way, or is there more to it behind the scenes?

Starting with Java so sorry if this is way too stupid of a question, but I couldn't find anything about this in the web.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

The two methods are equivalent. Note, however, that the concise syntax can only be used in variable declarations. Outside variable declarations you have to use the verbose syntax:

```
    String[] array;
    array = new String[] { "foo", "bar", "baz" }; // OK

    String[] array2;
    array2 = { "foo", "bar", "baz" };             // ERROR
```

For further discussion, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10520659/367273).

Answer (score 7):

> Is there any difference between these?

There is no difference in the end result. However, as per [the JLS § 10.6, you cannot use the array initializer synax in every context.](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-10.html#jls-10.6)

> An array initializer may be specified in a declaration ([§8.3](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.3), [§9.3](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-9.html#jls-9.3), [§14.4](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-14.html#jls-14.4)), or as part of an array creation expression ([§15.10](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.10)), to create an array and provide some initial values.

Comment: I do love spec links, thanks very much. But I believe NPE's answer is more clear/simpler for future Java starters that may come to read the question. +1 for both in any case. `=]`

Answer (score 0):

Since arrays are *intended* to be mutable, it makes sense that each one is a new instance

```
String[] array1 = { "foo", "bar", "baz" };
String[] array2 = { "foo", "bar", "baz" };
```

i.e. modifying `array1` won't affect `array2`.

Comment: I have a decent OO base and understand that each array is a new instance, the question was specifically whether `new String[]` made any difference in the initialization of the array.