# Understanding Java new Class[] array and implementation

Tags: java, arrays, class, generics

Begining Java

Can someone break down whats going on here

```
protected Class<?>[] getServletConfigClasses() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return new Class[] {
            WebApplicationContextConfig.class
    };
}
```

My understanding is that this is a method which expects its return to be an array of Class object of an unknown type

But what is the return? 
An instantiation of an anonymous Class object array without a constructor and its implementation block at the same time?

What's the name of this for further reading and I can't seem to find this subject area?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15177463/initializing-array-with-values-should-i-explicitly-instance-the-class-or-not

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no anonymous Class object. [`Class`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html) is a java class like any other, but with a name that is bound to confuse Java beginners.

the statement

```
return new Class[] {
            WebApplicationContextConfig.class
    };
```

is equivalent to

```
Class [] result = new Class[1];
result[0] = WebApplicationContextConfig.class;
return result;
```

`WebApplicationContextConfig.class` is called a [class literal](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.8.2), and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2160788/what-is-a-class-literal-in-java) is a some discussion about them.

Comment: Ah yes that makes sense, just like 'new String[]{"foo", "bar"};' is declaring an array of String and initialising it with values at the same time.

I guess the 'Class' threw me off. Cheers

Comment: @succeed: Exactly. Good coding,

Answer (score 1):

It is an array declared with default values. In Java it is short-hand way of making arrays.

```
String[] names = {"Arvind","Aarav"}; // initialization
```

Now to re-assign a completely new array.

```
names = new String[]{"Rajesh","Amit","Mahesh"}; //re-initalization
```

Same thing with methods, let us say, returning days of week

```
public String[] weekdays(){
    String[]days={"Sun","Mon","Tue"};
    return days;
}
```

OR

```
public String[] weekdays(){
    return new String[]{"Sun","Mon","Tue"};
}
```

Now about `Class[]`, for type `Class` possible value is `null` and `SomeClassName.class`.

```
Class stringClass = String.class;
Class[] moreClasses = {Long.class, Boolean.class, java.util.Date.class};
```

Answer (score 0):

It's just declaring an Array of [Class](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html) and initialize it with one element (The Class definition of WebApplicationContextConfig)

Answer (score 0):

It is array of wildcard type. See [this](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-4.html#jls-4.5.1) for more

Answer (score 0):

This is an array initializer.  When you say

```
new Something[] { x1, x2, x3 }
```

it creates a new array of the `Something` class, and initializes the values to whatever you tell it in the curly braces.  The length of the new array is the number of values.

I think you might be confusing it with a very similar syntax:

```
new Something() { class declarations, method overrides, etc. }
```

This one creates an anonymous subclass of `Something`, and it's used a lot for creating anonymous subclasses that implement interfaces.  It's not at all related to the array initializer syntax, even though the appearance is pretty close.