# Why can array constant only be used in initializer?

Tags: java, arrays

I am trying the following:

```
private int[] location=new int[3];

public void Location()
{
  this.location={1,2,3};//error is showing here
}
```

but getting the compile error like:

> array constant can only be used in initialize

I have have already declared object of array and trying to assign value to it. What is the issue?

I have seen [Why can array constants only be used in initializers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10520617/why-array-constants-can-only-be-used-in-initializers) but this is not proper explanation what I am seeking.

Comment: The answer in the linked question says “the syntax is only permitted in declarations”, and you say in your question you *already* declared it. You can only use that syntax *while* declaring, not after.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Arrays are little special, See the [language specification](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-10.html#jls-10.6)
, It's designed so

> Each variable initializer must be assignment-compatible (§5.2) with the array's component type, or a compile-time error occurs.

Initializer expression starts with `{}`  and with elements inside it.

*IMHO* Without telling the type to `{..}`  compiler confuses to know the actual type it should consists.

That notation `{..}` works with only while declartion place of the `array`. Otherwise you need that  **array creation expression**, which is `new type {..}`

Answer (score 3):

Because that's the syntax for a *declaration*.

You can get *similar* syntax with an array constructor (?):

```
this.location= new int[]{1,2,3};
```

---

Wait, this is what the *linked* answer said .. in any case, this is Just How It Is, but allowing the shorter `{..}` form *only* in declarations also avoids complications in general for expressions-that-can-create-arrays.

For instance, consider the following:

C#, with type inference, allows `new[] {..}` which is as bit shorter, but Java (7) doesn't have type inference so this isn't practical as the *type* of a array is not explicitly declared. Thus it wouldn't make sense to add a special expression grammar production (such that `new[] {..}` ~ `{..}`) in Java, even if one wanted to .. without going ahead and adding support for type inference (even if just localized to the specialized production).

The declaration doesn't have this problem because the initializers type is pinned to the type of the array being declared.

Comment: @sᴜʀᴇsʜᴀᴛᴛᴀ Yes, I edit alot (too much). Thanks for making me review my answer.

Answer (score 1):

```
private int[] location;

public void location() {
    this.location = new int[] {1, 2, 3};
}
```

Comment: OP is asking for an explanation. not for a snippet.