# Change values of array

Tags: java

There is going to be a different set of test scores for each students. How would I be able to change that parameter every time I make a new object? Is it possible to change its value like you would a double? I tried but it did not work. Thanks.

**StudentData**

```
 public class StudentData
{
  private NumberFormat fmt = NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance();

  private String firstName;
  private String lastName;
  private double[] testScores;
  private char grades;
  public double average;
  public double total;

  public StudentData (String firstName, String lastName, double[] scores)
  {
   this.firstName = firstName;
   this.lastName = lastName;

   grades = courseGrade( scores);

   if (scores.length == 0)
    throw new IllegalArgumentException("There are no grades for this student");
   else
    testScores = scores;
 }

  public char courseGrade(double[] list)
 {

   for ( int x = 0; x < list.length; x++)
    total += list[x];
   average = total/list.length;
   if (average >= 90)
     return 'A';
   if (average < 90 && average >= 80)
     return 'B';
   if (average < 80 && average >= 70)
     return 'C';
   if (average < 70 && average >= 60)
     return 'D';
   else
     return 'F';

 }

 public String toString()
 {
  return firstName + "    " + lastName + "   " + fmt.format(testScores);
 }
```

}

**TestProgStudentData**

```
public class TestProgStudentData
{
  public static void main(String[] args)
  {
    double[] scores;
    List<StudentData> students = new ArrayList<StudentData>();
    scores = {79.00, 94.00, 86.00, 72.00, 90.00};
    students.add(new StudentData("Gaby", "Gomez", scores));
    scores = {85.00, 67.00, 86.00, 100.00, 93.00};
    students.add(new StudentData("David", "Gomez", scores));

   for(StudentData f : students)
     System.out.println(f);

   }
}
```

Comment: Use args array of String to collect name and scores from command line

Comment: I think you would like to change "Gaby"'s scores without making a new object, is it right??

Comment: I don't understand, what do you want to change? `public StudentData (String firstName, String lastName, double[] scores)`?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to change the value of a score without creating a new object, then you should add a new function to do that:

```
public void changeScore(int index, double newScore)
{
    this.testScores[index] = newScore;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Array constants can only used in  initializers.**Compiler can't recognise the type of array.**

For example:

"a = {...}" it is not clear to the compiler what the type of

```
Object[] a;
a = {"Hello", "World"}; // use String[] or Object[] ?
```

It could look at the declared type (so Object[]) but because it's still ambiguous the compiler disallows it.

This is what you searching for  [Why can array constants only be used in initializers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10520617/why-array-constants-can-only-be-used-in-initializers)

Comment: you could have flagged this question as duplicate. (since you have put in a link to a similar topic ... )

Answer (score 0):

I would change the `ArrayList` completely to a better alternative. You will have to adjust your program somewhat, but it may work better:

```
StudentData student1 = new StudentData("Gaby", "Gomez", 79.00, 94.00, 86.00, 72.00, 90.00);
```

and then to display your results:

```
System.out.println(student1);
```

Answer (score 0):

Change your `StudentData` to accept the new varargs `...` param list

```
public StudentData (String firstName, String lastName, double... scores)
  {
   this.firstName = firstName;
   this.lastName = lastName;

   grades = courseGrade( scores);

   if (scores.length == 0)
    throw new IllegalArgumentException("There are no grades for this student");
   else
    testScores = scores;
 }
```

then change your tests to

```
students.add(new StudentData("Gaby", "Gomez", 79.00, 94.00, 86.00, 72.00, 90.00));
```