# Array Constants can only be used in initializers Error

Tags: java, arrays, swing

I am new to Java Programming.I want to fetch data from the database and show it in JTable.

This is my current code.

```
String columns[]={"Transaction_id","User_name","Amount","Recharge_Spending","Spend_by"};
Object data[][]=new Object[200][5]; 
int i=0;
while(rs.next())
{
    result_Transaction_id[i]=rs.getInt("f.Transaction_id");
    result_User_name[i]=rs.getString("U.User_name");
    data[i][5]={(Object)result_Transaction_id[i],(Object)result_User_name[i]};//This is where i get error
    ++i;
}
JTable View_table =new JTable(data,columns);
```

I want to collect the results of the query and add them in the specified object.
But i get the following error "Array constants can only be used in initializers".

I found a lot of solutions to "Array Constants can only be used in initializers" error, but those don't suit my case.

Comment: *Where* are you getting the error? (As an aside, I'd recommend that you put the `[]` for arrays with the type information: `String[] columns = ` etc. (And claiming this isn't a duplicate doesn't make it so. It would help if you'd give more details than just "but those don't suit my case".)

Answer (score 1):

An "array constant" means `{ ... }`.

As the error is trying to tell you, you can only use that syntax when declaring an array variable.

To assign an array to an existing expression, use `new TypeName[] { ... }`.

Comment: the problem ,but as i need to use the array dynamically to get data and store it .I am not able to do it like you suggested.

Comment: @Yuvi: Huh? Just replace your `{...}` literal with an actual array creation.  However, you should probably use `ArrayList<T>` instead.

Comment: Is that means ,thats not possible with normal array ?

Comment: @Yuvi: Read my answer more carefully.  It's just a difference between a variable declaration and a normal assignment.

Answer (score 1):

The error is the way you declare your array.

As stated here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/10520659/3558900 You can only declare an array NOT like this:

```
String columns[]={"Transaction_id","User_name","Amount","Recharge_Spending","Spend_by"};
```

BUT

```
String[] s;
s = new String[] {"Transaction_id","User_name","Amount","Recharge_Spending","Spend_by"};
```

Comment: ,i wanted to use dynamic variables and append it to the list .Its not static like you suggested ,so thats the problem for me

Comment: `String columns[]={"Transaction_id","User_name","Amount","Recharge_Spending","Spend_by"};`  compiles perfectly and is allowed (thou `String[ ] columns` is better code-style); 
What is not allowed by JLS is this: `String[] ar; ar = { "one", "two" };`
By the way `String[ ] ar;` is same as `String ar[ ];` and compiles for compatibility reasons.Thou `String[ ] ar;` is the preferred style.