# Initializing line in 2d array in Java

Tags: java, multidimensional-array

```
int arr[][] = new int[3][4];
int row[] = {1,2,3,4};
arr[0] = {1,2,3,4}; // why this doesn't work?
arr[0] = row; //when this line works
```

In above code, why we can't initialize row of array with `{1,2,3,4}` directly (on `line3`).

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1938101/how-to-initialize-an-array-in-java

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5387643/array-initialization-syntax-when-not-in-a-declaration

Comment: That is simply how the language is specified. After the variable is declared, you have to say `arr[0] = new int{...}`.

Comment: `{1,2,3,4}` Is called as array literal and you cannot use it without denoting it's type left of right side. That is how they got designed.

Comment: @ꜱᴜʀᴇꜱʜᴀᴛᴛᴀ no, it's called an [Array initializer](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se9/html/jls-10.html#jls-10.6).

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10520617/why-can-array-constants-only-be-used-in-initializers

Comment: In another words, for each row you have to use `new int[4]`, or explicitly initialize that row (like you did in the last statement). Good luck, Срђане