# Java - Displaying array using JTable

Tags: java, arrays, swing, jtable

I've made a program which reads a text file and organizes it into an array of floats. I'm now trying to display that array using JTable but despite hours of googling haven't found an answer to my problem.

My data array is created like this

```
//organize data
public void createDataArray(String[][] n) {
    for(int x=0; x<n.length;x++) {
        for(int y=0; y<n[x].length;y++) {
            switch(y) {
            case 0: 
                dataArray[x][y] = 0;
                break;
            case 1: 
                dataArray[x][y] = new Float(n[x][y]);
                break;
            case 2: 
                dataArray[x][y] = new Float(n[x][y]);
                break;
            case 3: 
                dataArray[x][y] = new Float(n[x][y]);
                break;
            case 4: 
                dataArray[x][y] = new Float(n[x][y]);
                break;
            case 5: 
                dataArray[x][y] = new Float(n[x][y]);
                break;
            case 6: 
                dataArray[x][y] = new Float(n[x][y]);
                break;
            case 7: 
                dataArray[x][y] = new Float(n[x][y]);
                break;

            }
        }
    }
}
```

I am trying to display this array using JTable, like so

```
table = new JTable(data, columnNames);
```

It works fine using this object...

```
Object[][] data = {
                {a.getDate(0), a.getStockPrice(0)},
                {a.getDate(1), a.getStockPrice(1)},
    };
```

However I need to find a way to display the data directly from my data array.
I tried defining the object using for loops but I get the error "Array constants can only be used in initializes".

I know this is a pretty basic question but any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: I did a quick test and seems to work just fine. One thing that does worry me is, you seem to have your data in col/row order, where `JTable` will prefer it in row/col order.

Comment: It's hard to tell where or why you're having problems. Consider providing a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) which will remove the guess work

Comment: Possible duplicate [Why can array constants only be used in initializers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10520617/why-can-array-constants-only-be-used-in-initializers?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa)

Comment: By the way: Given 6 of the 7 cases in the switch do exactly the same thing, it'd be shorter code to simply use an `if (0) .. else ..`.

Comment: @MadProgrammer Where I get my error is when I try to input my dataArray into JTable. I get the error "the constructor JTable(float[][], String[]) is undefined". It seems that it won't accept float[][] as a parameter..?

Comment: Ahh, well, that's a different error. Primitive arrays are not the same thing as object arrays, Java won't autobox those.  Instead of `float[][]` use `Float[][]`

Comment: @MadProgrammer damn it was as easy as that. thank you!

Comment: @jonn_ey Welcome to the brick wall, plenty of space for all ;)

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
for(int i = 0; i< dataArray[0].length ; i++){

Object[] row = {dataArray[i][0],dataArray[i][1]};
            DefaultTableModel model = (DefaultTableModel) table.getModel();
            model.addRow(row); 

}
```

this only works if dataArray[][] has always the same length on both columns