# Arrays shortcut syntax dilemma | Java Programming language

Tags: java, arrays, multidimensional-array

If the following Java code is valid:

```
int[] anotherIntArray = {1, 2, 3, 4};
```

Then why is the below code:

```
String[][] anotherStrings = new String[2][];
anotherStrings[0] = {"Mr.", "Mrs."};
```

giving below error:

> Array constants can only be used in initializers

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10520617/why-can-array-constants-only-be-used-in-initializers

Comment: The error message answers your question: "Array constants can only be used in initializers". `anotherStrings[0] = ...` is simple assignment, not an initialiser.