# Why can't i construct string array like this in Java?

Tags: java, arrays, compiler-errors, initialization

I am trying to initialize a string array like below but it has an error.

```
public class Account{
    private String[] account;

    public Account()
    {
        account = {"A", "B", "C"};
    }
}
```

Does anyone knows why it keep creating an error?

Comment: You need to initilize the array

Comment: *"it has an error."*  Copy/paste the error text as an [edit to the question](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/15872566/edit) & use code formatting.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The correct syntax to use inside the constructor is

```
account = new String[]{"A", "B", "C"};
```

The shortcut syntax you are trying to use is only permitted at the point of declaration:

```
private String[] account = {"A", "B", "C"};
```

As to *why* the distinction, see [Why can array constants only be used in initializers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10520617/why-array-constants-can-only-be-used-in-initializer)

Answer (score 0):

Refer: [Arrays constants can only be used in initializers error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6348479/arrays-constants-can-only-be-used-in-initializers-error)

Also Refer: [Why can array constants only be used in initializers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10520617/why-array-constants-can-only-be-used-in-initializer)

"If you want to use the array initializer, you cannot split the declaration and assignment."