# Array constants can only be used in initializers when trying to initialize an array?

Tags: java, arrays, initialization

Given the following :

```
public class Actions 
{


    private MyMatrix matrix_1;
    private MyMatrix matrix_2;
    private MyMatrix transformMatrix;
    private final int VW = 40;
    private final int VH = 40;

    public static double[][] translateMatrixArr;


    public Edge doTransofrm(double xPoint,double yPoint,Edge myEdge,int transformType)
    {
        switch(transformType)
        {
        case 1:
            // initializations 
            Actions.translateMatrixArr = {{1.,0.,xPoint},{0.,1.,yPoint},{0.,0.,1.}};
            break;
        case 2:
            Actions.translateMatrixArr = // something else 
            break;
        case 3:
            Actions.translateMatrixArr = // something else

        }

        return null;
    }


...


}
```

I tried to do like what @joschi said [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6348479/arrays-constants-can-only-be-used-in-initializers-error) , but it doesn't work . Any way around this ?

Regards

Comment: "I tried to do like what @joschi said here, but it doesn't work" Doesn't work in what sense?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use `new` to create instances of arrays:

```
Actions.translateMatrixArr = new double[][]{
    new double[] {1.,0.,xPoint}
,   new double[] {0.,1.,yPoint}
,   new double[] {0.,0.,1.}
};
```