# How to resolve the expected semicolon error in Java?

Tags: java, jtable, jfreechart

I have the `";" expected` error and I already tried to put the ";" but in vain. This is the code:

```
 public static XYZDataset createDataset(JTable table )
   {
    DefaultXYZDataset defaultxyzdataset = new DefaultXYZDataset();

    DefaultTableModel dtm = (DefaultTableModel) table.getModel();
    int nRow = dtm.getRowCount(), nCol = dtm.getColumnCount();
    double[][] ad = new double[nRow][1];
    double[][] ad1 = new double[nRow][1];
    double[][] ad2 = new double[nRow][1];
    double ad3[][]=null;

    for (int i = 0 ; i < nRow ; i++)
           {
              ad[i] = (double[]) dtm.getValueAt(i,1);
              ad1[i] = (double[]) dtm.getValueAt(i,2);
               ad2[i] = (double[]) dtm.getValueAt(i,3);
               ad3[][]={ad[i],ad1[i],ad2[i]}  ;
           }

      defaultxyzdataset.addSeries( "Series 1" , ad3 );               
      return defaultxyzdataset; 
   }
```

I have the error on this line: `ad3[][]={ad[i],ad1[i],ad2[i]}`

Comment: Are you trying to assign each row of ad3 for each iteration of the loop? In other words set the values of ad, ad1, and ad2 at position i to the row i of ad3?

Comment: The problem is always present.

Comment: `The problem is always present` That doesn't answer my question...how exactly do you wish to convert the TableModel data to a DefaultXYZDataset?

Answer (score 1):

try

```
 public static XYZDataset createDataset(JTable table )
   {
    DefaultXYZDataset defaultxyzdataset = new DefaultXYZDataset();

    DefaultTableModel dtm = (DefaultTableModel) table.getModel();
    int nRow = dtm.getRowCount(), nCol = dtm.getColumnCount();
    double[][] ad = new double[nRow][1];
    double[][] ad1 = new double[nRow][1];
    double[][] ad2 = new double[nRow][1];
    double ad3[][][]= new double[nRow][3][1];

    for (int i = 0 ; i < nRow ; i++)
           {
               ad[i] = (double[]) dtm.getValueAt(i,1);
               ad1[i] = (double[]) dtm.getValueAt(i,2);
               ad2[i] = (double[]) dtm.getValueAt(i,3);
               ad3[i]={ad[i],ad1[i],ad2[i]} ;
           }

      defaultxyzdataset.addSeries( "Series 1" , ad3 );               
      return defaultxyzdataset; 
   }
```

Your current code is trying to assign an array to nothing really since ad3[][] has no interpretative meaning without some numbers in the [].

Answer (score 0):

Array constants can only be used in [array initializers](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-10.html#jls-10.6); use this statement instead:

```
ad3 = new double[][]{ad[i],ad1[i],ad2[i]};
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't use array constants after array initialization.  If you declare and initialize ad3 in the loop it would work or if you do this:

```java
ad3= new double[][]{ad[i],ad1[i],ad2[i]}  ;
```

See this previous [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6348479/arrays-constants-can-only-be-used-in-initializers-error) for further discussion.

Answer (score 0):

1. First of all ad3 is not initialized .
2. Secondly as far as i know you cannot add element to array like the
   one you have done. ad3[][]={ad[i],ad1[i],ad2[i]}  ;
3. If you want to do you can do like this:
           int [][] arr = new int [5][5];
           arr[1] = new int []{1,2,3,4,5};
            arr[2] = new int []{1,2,3,4,5};

Answer (score 0):

The error is caused by the way you are assigning a value to `ad3` inside the loop. Assuming that you really want to assign a new value to that array during for each iteration, you'll have to change that line as follows:

`ad3 = new double[][] {ad[i],ad1[i],ad2[i]};`

Please be aware though, that after the loop that means the contents of `ad3` will be `ad[nRow - 1]`, `ad1[nRow - 1]`, and `add[nRow - 1]` - it is not clear why you are using a loop at all in that case.

Answer (score 0):

I resolved the problem, 
this is the new code

```js
 public static XYZDataset createDataset(JTable table )
   {
    DefaultXYZDataset defaultxyzdataset = new DefaultXYZDataset();
    
    DefaultTableModel dtm = (DefaultTableModel) table.getModel();
    int nRow = dtm.getRowCount(), nCol = dtm.getColumnCount();
    
    for (int i = 0 ; i < nRow ; i++)
           {
              double ad [ ] = { (double)dtm.getValueAt(i, 1)};
              double ad1 [ ] = { (double)dtm.getValueAt(i, 2)};
              double ad2 [ ] = { (double)dtm.getValueAt(i, 3)};
              double ad3[][]={ad,ad1,ad2}  ;        
           }
    
                                     
      defaultxyzdataset.addSeries( "Series 1" , ad3 );               
      return defaultxyzdataset; 
   }
```