# Why am i unable to add an array as an instance field?

Tags: java

I wanted to add an array as an instance field, also a part of an object, however it gives me interesting errors when i try to do so:

```
class Surgeon {
  private String[] surgeons;

  public Surgeon() {
    this.surgeons = {"Romero", "Jackson", "Hannah", "Camilla"};
  }

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    Surgeon surg = new Surgeon();
  }
}
```

And it gives me three errors.

This does not make any sense bc is it not how you initialize an array?

Comment: "*And it gives me three errors.*" - Please [edit] the post and include the errors.

Comment: The correct syntax is: `this.surgeons = new String[] {"Romero", "Jackson", "Hannah", "Camilla"};`

Comment: I am curious as to what the other two errors were (since there was only one in the posted code).

Comment: @hfontanez I use `Eclipse` and got one error and one warning (`surg` not used).  I would imagine it depends on the ide and the error settings.

Comment: @WJS Elclipse is a very hard IDE to use in my opinion, i rather use IntelliJ IDEA

Comment: @WJS But you and I know warnings are not errors. That's why I am curious about what the other two "errors" were. My guess is that the OP had more broken code in the same project that had nothing to do with this particular issue.

Comment: @hfontanez That's why I mentioned the ide and settings.  I can set some warnings to be errors if I want.  Or just ignore them completely.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Arrays constants can only be used in initializers error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6348479/arrays-constants-can-only-be-used-in-initializers-error)

Comment: Please review https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1200621/how-do-i-declare-and-initialize-an-array-in-java

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to add the operator "new" to instantiate the array in the class constructor

```
public Surgeon() {
this.surgeons = new String[]{"Romero", "Jackson", "Hannah", "Camilla"};
}
```